# .NET Throw exception / raise event after X number of seconds

Tags: c#, .net

In a long running C# method I want to throw an exception or raise an event after a number of seconds have elapsed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use [System.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried using a `Timer`? I can only think that the exception will not be raised on the thread that your method runs on.

Comment: @Habib did you consider that the exception will occur on a different thread and therefore the method would most likely continue? Not as simple as that I don't think?

Comment: @LukeHennerley, OP can raise an event or timer elapsed event and that event can be caught else where

Comment: Timer is good as it will invoke a method on a period. But, that begs the issue of threads. So perhaps the real question is 'who cares'. If we know who cares that the method is taking a long time then we can give a better answer.

Comment: Why is it long running? This is an important question in really answering your question. The answer may be very different if your method is waiting for third party responses or if it is processing time issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using a timer - set it for the timeout you wish and start it at the start of the method.

At the very end of the method, disable the timer - it will only fire if it times out and you can hook up to the tick event.

```
var timer = new Timer(timeout);
timer.Elapsed = ElapsedEventHanler; // Name of the event handler
timer.Start();

// do long running process

timer.Stop();
```

I suggest reading up on the [different timer classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) - this will let you know which of them is best suited for your particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to stop a long running method then I think adding Cancellation support to the method would be a better approach instead of raising the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which has functionality for cancelling the exception (if the process completed) and raises the exception on the source thread:

```
var targetThreadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    var ct = cancellationToken;

    // How long the process has to run
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    // Exit the thread if the process completed
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Throw exception to target thread
    targetThreadDispatcher.Invoke(() => throw new MyExceptionClass());
}, cancellationToken);

RunProcess();

// Cancel the exception raising if the process was completed.
tokenSource.Cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Threading.Timer:

```
System.Threading.Timer t;
int seconds = 0;

public void start() {

    TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(tick);
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb);
    t.Change(0, 1000);          
}

public void tick(object o)
{
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```